# Взаимодействие рабочих потоков с GUI

Tags: gui, winforms, проектирование, lock-free, многопоточность

Интересуют реализации взаимодействия рабочих потоков с GUI со стороны рабочих потоков.

Например, загрузка файла с сервера выполняется в выделенном потоке. Этот поток должен сообщать юзеру о прогрессе загрузки через какой-нибудь прогрессбар. Но доступ к прогрессбару имеет только поток, владеющий родительским окном.

В .NET часто используются методы Control.Invoke() и Control.BeginInvoke()/Control.EndInvoke().
Этот вариант вполне годится, когда одна итерация фоновой задачи требует значительно большего времени, чем отображение прогресса. Но он превращается в толстую прибавку к длительности выполнения фоновой задачи, когда итераций много и время выполнения каждой такой итерации сравнима с временем, которое рабочий поток тратит на уведомление о прогрессе.

Я в таком случае добавляю коллбек в lockfree-очередь и с помощью PostMessage уведомляю об этом владеющий окном поток. В переопределенном методе WndProc последовательно выбираю и выполняю все коллбеки из очереди. Таким образом, накладные расходы сводятся к минимуму.

Какие подходы применяете вы? Платформа и язык не важны, будут интересны все случаи.

Answer (score 5):

> Я в таком случае добавляю коллбек в lockfree-очередь и с помощью PostMessage уведомляю об этом владеющий окном поток. В переопределенном методе WndProc последовательно выбираю и выполняю все коллбеки из очереди. Таким образом, накладные расходы сводятся к минимуму.

У Вас самый хороший вариант. Только я бы добавил ограничение по времени на период опроса очереди в `WndProc`, т.е. если `lockfree-очередь` не заканчивается к примеру через `100мс` - завершать обработку текущего сообщения принудительно, чтобы избежать подвисаний `GUI`.

**Миграция комментариев:**

Я думаю, на самом деле такую проверку даже в `WndProc` делать нежелательно, поскольку это означает, что на каждый элемент очереди **синхронизации** в очереди **потока** висит сообщение, посланное `post'ом`.
 --
Чтобы избежать холостой перегрузки очереди потока, лучше вырабатывать очередь `lockfree` не по сообщению, а по **событию** (неавтомату [или **семафору**, в роли дросселя, это более безопасно]) в каком-нибудь отдельном потоке, который выбрав из очереди синхронизации, к примеру `100мс-узлов` - отправит один `post` в очередь потока с этим, уже выбранным списком.
 --
`100мс-узлов` - это число узлов, выбранное из очереди за не более `100мс`.
 --
Вобщем-то, в таком случае, очередь безболезненно заменяется на простой стек `lockfree`: `push` - в прямом порядке, `pop` - в обратном, но последний `push`, который формирует очередь `100мс-узлов`, опять вернет прямой порядок узлов.
 --
Могу только опять заметить, что даже в такой ситуации от подвисания `GUI` гарантий нет, т.к. мы ничего не знаем, что творится в самих коллбеках. Но вот этот момент и можно уже ограничивать непосредственно в `WndProc`, отправляя "слишком долгие коллбеки" на повторный круг - аналог `post'а`, только в очереди **синхронизации**.
 --
После этого, повесить `GUI` сможет только уже **один конкретный колбек**, но это уже проблема программиста, который решил все впихнуть в одну лямбду, к нему и претензии.

**Дискуссия:**

> В ста миллисекундах 100000000 наносекунд; если задержка в десяток наносекунд, происходящая раз в 100000000 наносекунд, мешает вашему алгоритму, что же говорить про context switch?

Во первых, [[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd), я не говорил о задержке раз в `100мс`, а во-вторых, не говорил, что она мешает. Она **меняет** логику работы алгоритма, работающего на `lock-free-скоростях`.
 --
У меня есть такое понятие, как "ожидание свободного ресурса", т.е., если через какой-то промежуток времени из стека `lock-free` не будет извлечен ресурс, то создается новый. Вот я и нашел такой временнОй диапазон, который влияет на итоговый объем задействованного ресурса задачей.

К примеру: при ожидании ресурса **более** `30нс` - итоговое число ресурсов примерно ограничено числом ядер(в моем случае - `~7-8`), независимо от числа подзадач(`~30-70` штук), его использующих, а вот на `10нс`, это число составляет примерно `70%` от числа подзадач. Конечно, такие задержки можно делать только на основе показаний [`TSC`](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TSC), о чем я сразу и сказал.

> Вы уверены, что с вашим кодом всё в порядке?

Поверьте, у меня было достаточно времени его проверить :)

> Или вы всё же немного приукрасили для большей выпуклости аргумента?

А Вы сами в это можете поверить? У меня хорошая репутация, зачем мне ее портить?

Comment: Да, идея хорошая. Спасибо.

Comment: переместил комментарии, ибо жалко :)

Comment: Переместил и расширил в ответе.

Comment: >документация WPF не гарантирует наличие WinAPI-шного окна

А у Вас богатая фантазия, @VladD, по поводу перспектив отвязки какого-либо продукта **от окон** на OS Windows. :) Мне кажется, Вы неправильно понимаете документацию. Возможно имелось ввиду, что какие-то отдельные компоненты могут в перспективе лишиться физического окна, но ни как не сама `WPF`.

Comment: Поскольку глючный хэшкод ограничивает количество комментариев, продолжаем разговор здесь :)

>> VladD: Я думаю, лишние хэндлы съест сборка мусора.

Съест, но не сразу, а при сворачивании/разворачивании окна. А до этого момента они будут накапливаться.

Comment: >> Если стандартная доставка сообщений вдруг слишком медленна (что по факту не так, если мы не делаем явных глупостей типа 1М обновлений в секунду),

Она либо медленна, либо создает дескрипторы, которые самостоятельно не уничтожатся. Да и вообще WaitHandle там не нужен.

Answer (score 3):

Я лично пользуюсь `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` в WPF (аналог `Control.BeginInvoke`). Низкоуровневые штуки типа `PostMessage` кажутся мне хаком, никто не гарантирует, что окна в WPF всегда будут основаны на WinAPI-шных окнах (Silverlight? WinRT?). Обновлять UI так часто, чтобы аж затраты на обновление были существенны, не имеет смысла, так как всё равно юзер не в состоянии осознать столь быстрые изменения. Поэтому я ограничиваю снизу время между последовательными обновлениями прогресса, скажем, эмпирической сотней миллисекунд.

Kонцептуально более правильным решением было бы использование [Rx Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609) для push-нотификаций, но я пока не научился хорошо с ними работать.

Comment: >Обновлять UI так часто, чтобы аж затраты на обновление были существенны, не имеет смысла, так как всё равно юзер не в состоянии осознать столь быстрые изменения.

На данный момент парк ПК даже в одной конторе может быть настолько разнообразным по производительности, что одни и те же программы могут на нем вести себя совершенно иначе, чем ожидается. Обычно люди говорят - старые машины не тянут, виснут. А вот - не всегда. Часто бывает так, что как раз тянут, но больше чем требуется из-за того, что не предусмотрены такие перегрузки в программе.

Comment: >Поэтому я ограничиваю снизу время между последовательными обновлениями прогресса, скажем, эмпирической сотней миллисекунд.

Вопрос ведь не про конкретную реализацию. В общем случае такой механизм требуется в потоке тогда, когда в нем идет какая-то долгосрочная обработка данных. Ваша эмпирическая сотня миллисекунд в такой ситуации будет превращать эту задачу в цирк для одного актера. Т.е. призводительность задачи будет напрямую зависеть от этой сотни. В многопоточном программировании принято отделять реализацию от сбора статистики. И Ваш вариант тут будет всегда проигрывать.

Comment: >И Ваш вариант тут будет всегда проигрывать

Конечно, если эту сотню выбудете явно "простаивать" в потоке. И в системе не будет другой параллельной линейки расчетов, которая использует ту же очередь синхронизации `GUI`.

Comment: @mega: прежде всего прагматика: если производительность машины настолько низка, что даже обновление интерфейса раз в 100 мс приводит к видимым задержкам -- выбросьте наконец уже этот Pentium II!

Никаких ожиданий и простоев не нужно, что вы. Я такого и не предлагал. Просто перед обновлением прогресса нужно проверить timestamp последнего обновления, и если 100 мс не прошло, ничего не обновлять.

Отделять реализацию вычислений от UI-логики конечно надо. Для этого просто инкапсулируйте логику обновления UI из другого потока в отдельный класс, проблем вообще не вижу.

Comment: @mega: насчёт большого количества потоков: если у вас в системе, скажем, не более 5 потоков, и каждый обновляет UI не чаще чем раз в 100 мс, по моему опыту всё в порядке. Если же у вас десятки/сотни потоков (оставим в стороне вопрос оптимальности такой архитектуры), то обновлением статистики должна заниматься центральная компонента, так что запросы на обновление UI будут идти из одного потока снова-таки не более чем раз в 100 мс.

Comment: >Отделять реализацию вычислений от UI-логики конечно надо. Для этого просто инкапсулируйте логику обновления UI из другого потока в отдельный класс, проблем вообще не вижу.

Если бы все проблемы так решались, то и проблем бы не было. :) Очевидно, я затрагиваю **не** проблему `ООП`. Существуют задачи, для которых издержки на отправке сообщения в поток играют огромную роль.  
 --  
Я вот буквально вчера отметил, что даже задержка в диапазоне **наносекунд** может повлиять на характер работы алгоритма (это буквально десятки отсчетов `TSC`), что уж говорить о `PostMessage` или `PostThreadMessage`.

Comment: @mega: Вы уверены, что с вашим кодом всё в порядке? В ста миллисекундах 100000000 наносекунд; если задержка в десяток наносекунд, происходящая **раз в 100000000 наносекунд**, мешает вашему алгоритму, что же говорить про context switch? В этом случае вам нужна RTOS, а UI не нужен вообще. Или вы всё же немного приукрасили для большей выпуклости аргумента?

Comment: Ограничение частоты обновления интерфейса - логично, да.

>> Низкоуровневые штуки типа PostMessage кажутся мне хаком

Ггг, докатились :)

>> никто не гарантирует, что окна в WPF всегда будут основаны на WinAPI-шных окнах

Для общего случая PostMessage, конечно, не годится. Так-то GUI и многопоточные бывают. Но для однопоточных GUI суть остается та же: затолкнуть коллбек в очередь, которую проверит поток GUI.

Comment: @Flammable: документация WPF не гарантирует наличие WinAPI-шного окна, поэтому то, что `PostMessage` работает -- случайность, основанная на специфике текущей реализации. Такой подход и есть хак, разве нет? Подход с `BeginInvoke` (ни в коем случае не `Invoke`!) по документации обязан работать. Как именно реализована доставка сообщений в поток, нисколько не интересная низкоуровневая деталь. Мне кажется, правильнее думать надо об очередях, а о семантике: такой-то код выполняется в таком-то контексте.

Comment: >> документация WPF не гарантирует наличие WinAPI-шного окна, поэтому то, что PostMessage работает -- случайность, основанная на специфике текущей реализации. Такой подход и есть хак, разве нет?

Так я не спорю, просто само по себе утверждение показалось забавным :)

>> Подход с BeginInvoke (ни в коем случае не Invoke!) по документации обязан работать.

Главное не забыть организовать EndInvoke, а то получатся прикольные цифры в колонке "Handles" таскменеджера. Красиво организовать у меня когда-то не получилось, и я забил на асинхронность.

Comment: >> Как именно реализована доставка сообщений в поток, нисколько не интересная низкоуровневая деталь

Еще как интересная. Если там между делом будет выполняться что-то тормозное, то меня такая реализация не устроит. Вот, кстати, что происходит внутри Invoke/BeginInvoke:

Comment: Marshaling an invoke occurs in three steps: 
    
    1.  Create a ThreadMethodEntry that contains the packet of information 
        about this invoke.  This TME is placed on a linked list of entries becaus
        we have a gap between the time we PostMessage and the time it actually
        gets processed, and this gap may allow other invokes to come in.  Access
        to this linked list is always synchronized. 
    
    2.  Post ourselves a message.  Our caller has already determined the 
        best control to call us on, and we should almost always have a handle.

Comment: 3.  If we're synchronous, wait for the message to get processed.  We don't do
        a SendMessage here so we're compatible with OLE, which will abort many
        types of calls if we're within a SendMessage.

Comment: @Flammable: странно, мне всегда казалось, `EndInvoke` почти никогда не нужен в подобных сценариях. У меня его отсутствие не вызывало проблем. Да и Microsoft вроде бы рекомендует одиночный BeginInvoke. Я думаю, лишние хэндлы съест сборка мусора.

Comment: @Flammable: подробности реализации `Invoke` интересны сами по себе, но программист в нормальной ситуации должен думать просто "этот код выполняется в том контексте". Если программист должен думать о низкоуровневых вещах в высокоуровневом коде, возникает ужасный, сложный в поддержке дизайн. Если стандартная доставка сообщений вдруг _слишком_ медленна (что по факту не так, если мы не делаем явных глупостей типа 1М обновлений в секунду), отделяем доставку в отдельную сущность, ускоряем/отлаживаем и забываем о низком уровне навсегда.