# Изменение richTextBox в потоке

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность, gui, .net

есть метод

```
public static void GetMessages()
        {               string Message = "12345"
                        ChatBox.AppendText(Message + Environment.NewLine);
                        ChatBox.SelectionStart = form.ChatBox.TextLength;
                        ChatBox.ScrollToCaret();
        }
```

который запускается в отдельном потоке. Вылезает ошибка при попытке обращения к richTextBox(ChatBox). Как мне изменить ChatBox из этого метода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оконная система Windows использует однопоточную модель апартаментов (STA), поэтому обращаться к контролу можно только из того потока, который его создал.
Самый простой способ решения этой проблемы - проверка свойства Control.InvokeRequired и вызов метода [Control.Invoke()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke.aspx).

Кстати, этот способ не единственный. Второй вариант описан [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/181948/winforms-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-gui).