# Открытие файла в отдельном потоке

Tags: c#, wpf, потоки-данных, многопоточность

Здравствуйте!
Имеется метод OpenText(index, numindex); который загружает текстовый файл в RichTextBox.
В это время что то происходит на форме. Поскольку есть большие достаточно по обьему файлы, они естественно грузятся не моментально и в момент их загрузки все приложение замораживается... Что мне сделать, чтобы файл грузился в отдельном потоке? я уже неделю пытаюсь разобраться, и ничего не получается.
Пробовал

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate()
            {
                OpenText(index, numindex);
            }));
```

все равно, все приложение замораживается на время загрузки. Другими способами, постоянно вылетают исключения ("Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту, так как владельцем этого объекта является другой поток.")

Задача - приложение, что то вроде электронного учебника, текст с картинками... другого способа кроме как RTF файлы, я не придумал)

Comment: А чем не подходят советы [отсюда](questions/222414/)?

Comment: не получается у меня, тупой наверно что разжевывать нужно(
я честно как только не пытался, везде натыкаюсь на "Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту, так как владельцем этого объекта является другой поток."

Comment: Ну, смотрите.

1. Открытие и разбор файла **должны быть** не в главном потоке — то есть, запущены отдельным заданием. Это можно делать по-всякому.
2. По окончанию работы задания нужно в **главном** потоке создать структуры, к которым будет binding, и
3. Обновить визуальные элементы (лучше всего через datacontext, но можно и вручную).

---
`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` — неправильный способ запустить задание в отдельном потоке, т.к. это запускает задание в **главном** потоке. Пользуйтесь другими методами.

Comment: "Пользуйтесь другими методами."
я пытаюсь, но пока безуспешно.

Comment: А что вы пробовали? `new Thread(...).Start()`? `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()`? `BackgroundWorker`? `Task.Run`? `async/await`?

Comment: new Thread(...).Start(),Task.Run, async/await с ними вылетает "Вызывающий поток не может получить доступ к данному объекту, так как владельцем этого объекта является другой поток." 
BackgroundWorker - вообще не понял как пользоваться, нашел пример где запускается метод не принимающий никаких аргументов, у меня другой случай.
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem() - впервые от вас о нем слышу)

Comment: Скорее всего, вы пытаетесь одновременно произвести разбор данных и создание визуальных элементов в отдельном потоке. Не делайте так, проводите чтение и разбор в одном потоке, а построение визуальных элементов — в главном.

Comment: Код:

    var tr = new TextRange(rtf.Document.ContentStart, rtf.Document.ContentEnd);
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(TextURI, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
                    tr.Load(fs, DataFormats.Rtf);
                    fs.Close();    
    
так я загружаю документ в richtextbox, и вылетает "Вызывающий поток не может..."
TextURI - берется их XML файла   
      
"Поток был недоступен для чтения." так получается если 
    
     Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate()
                    {  tr.Load(fs, DataFormats.Rtf);
                        
                    }));

Comment: Ну, я же вам именно это и говорю: вы работаете с `rtf.Document` не в главном потоке.

Comment: Проблема-то не в том откуда TextURI берется, а в строке tr.Load(...), который с RichTextBox связан, на нее же ругается? Этот метод и надо в таком случае через BeginInvoke вызывать.

Comment: @spawn: хм, тогда, возможно, снова-таки будет тормозить. По крайней мере, понятно, в чём проблема.

Comment: @VladD, будет, еще как :-)

Большой по объему файл так или иначе трудно загрузить, разве что кусками...

А в чем собственно состоит задача? Текстовый редактор?

Answer (score 2):

Ваш `Dispatcher`, очевидно, связан с GUI потоком и выполняет в нем метод `OpenText`, поэтому вы и получаете тормоза во время загрузки.
Используйте те самые другие способы, о которых вы написали в конце. Вылетающие исключения обусловлены тем, что вы пытаетесь получить доступ к элементам управления окна из своего нового потока, в то время как разрешен такой доступ только тому потоку, в котором эти элементы управления были созданы. Собственно, [уже отвечал на подобный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/192689/c-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-richtextbox-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5).

Comment: но в вашем примере WinForms, а тут WPF

Comment: @blackoverdose, и WinForms и WPF запрещают обращаться к элементам из другого потока, просто в первом случае используется ISyncronizeInvoke, во втором Dispatcher.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку разбор данных выполняется самим FlowDocument, выгрузить его в фоновый поток будет сложно.

Попробуйте следующее:

1. Загрузите данные с диска в MemoryStream в фоновом потоке. Потом в главном потоке создайте документ из этого `MemoryStream`'а.
2. Воспользуйтесь советом [отсюда](http://www.wiredprairie.us/journal/2007/05/creating_wpf_flowdocuments_on.html):

   - В фоновом потоке грузим новый, временный `FlowDocument` из файла. Поскольку этот `FlowDocument` создан не в UI-потоке, пользоваться им для отображения нельзя. Но он распарсит наш документ.
   - Просим его (временный `FlowDocument`) сохранить содержимое в `MemoryStream` как XAML. Этот `MemoryStream` можно перекинуть в UI-поток.
   - В UI-потоке грузим настоящий, рабочий `FlowDocument` из `MemoryStream`'а. Надеемся, что теперь парсинг произойдёт быстрее.

Comment: из того пример ошибки)

      
    FlowDocument docc = new FlowDocument(new Paragraph(new Run("hi")));
                    System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                    XamlWriter.Save(docc, stream);
                    stream.Position = 0;

                    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (ZeroDelegate)delegate()
                    {
                        flowDoc = (FlowDocument)XamlReader.Load(stream);
                    }
                    );

Comment: flowdoc - the name does not exit in current context.
ZeroDelegate - thetype or namespase name could not be found

Comment: Вы откуда этот тип вообще взяли?) ZeroDelegate

Comment: Для начала постарайтесь понять пример...

И в примере загружается не просто текстовый файл, а XAML, который заранее сохранили в файл.

Comment: не получается, так же стоит на месте

Comment: Что значит "так же стоит на месте"?

Comment: замораживается окно до тех пор, пока файл не загрузится.
что я опять не так делаю?)
    
      FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(TextURI);
                    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate()
                    {
                       var tr = new TextRange(rtf.Document.ContentStart, rtf.Document.ContentEnd);
                        tr.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf); 
                        stream.Close();
                    }));

Comment: @blackoverdose: Вы уснули, просыпайтесь. Ваш код грузит документ из **файла** в UI-потоке:

    FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(TextURI);
    ...
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...
    ...
    tr.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);

А нам надо грузить из файла в **фоновом** потоке, сохранять в MemoryStream, и грузить из MemoryStream'а в UI-потоке. Разницу видите?

Answer (score 1):

Единственный на мой взгляд адекватный способ открыть большой файл и при этом не заморозить окно - постепенное считывание файла.

Как минимум один минус - длительное использование файла.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="AsyncRTF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <RichTextBox>
            <FlowDocument Name="doc"/>
        </RichTextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Думаю не отличается от Вашего, но чтобы было всё понятно.

Codebehind:

```
private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Run run = new Run();
    doc.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(run));
    using (var fs = new StreamReader(new FileStream("d:\\1.txt", FileMode.Open)))
        while (!fs.EndOfStream)
        {
            run.Text += await fs.ReadLineAsync();
            run.Text += Environment.NewLine;
            await Task.Delay(10);
        }
}
```

Как видим, на событии загрузки окна, которое мы отмечаем как используемое асинхронно, создаём Run, затем открываем поток (в моём случае файлик на диске D, в котором, к слову, 85 мегабайт и 10 миллионов строк. Ну а затем читаем по строчке и даём GUI по 10 миллисекунд передышки.

Математика проста, открываться такое чудо будет очень долго. Скролл работать не будет, ну и не забывайте, что конкатенация строк вообще дело прожорливое. Открыть очень большой файл в любом случае сложно.

Но главная задача решена - окно можно двигать и кнопочки нажимать, пока загружается файл.

Comment: @Spawn: эээ... Файл-то в rtf, его построчно читать не получится.

Comment: Почему вы считаете неадекватным вариант с загрузкой файла в отдельном потоке?

Comment: @VladD, допустим, также открыть весь и подготовить к постепенной загрузке. Не самая простая задача, пожалуй, но Microsoft-то справляется в Word'е) Как и ребята из OpenOffice

@Flammable, неправильно выразился, пожалуй. Не постепенное считывание самого файла, а скорее постепенный парсинг, ибо как правильно заметил @VladD, построчно не всё прочитать получится.

Comment: @Spawn: Microsoft'у проще, у них есть отдельный парсер :-)

Comment: Честно говоря, довольно плохо помню структуру RTF, но даже при блочном считывании (ReadBlockAsync) думаю можно сделать постепенное распарсивание. Довольно много мусора приходится так самому разгребать (работаю с СУБД одной через telnet ^_^)

Comment: @Spawn: Это да, но ТС не хочет парсить сам, FlowDocument кагбе может распарсить за него.

Comment: ничего у меня не выходит(

Comment: я уже незнаю что делать если честно, прям руки опускаются. но оставлять в таком плачевном состоянии тоже не хочется((

Comment: Какой размер файла-то? Посмотрите вон на WordPad обычный, с крупными файлами он тоже долго мучается...

Comment: да мне нужно чтобы форма просто не замерзала когда файл открывается, интерфейс анимированый. файл больше 20 метров, все останавливает к чертям. я уже как ни пытался все в отдельные потоки запихнуть, ничего не выходит. я даже саму анимацию в отдельные потоки пихал и все бестолку.