# Как правильно выполнить метод в отдельном потоке?

Tags: c#, wpf, потоки-данных, многопоточность

Не могу сообразить как же все-таки вытащить метод в отдельный поток. Прошу помощи в разжевывании информации о работе с потоками.

Есть момент когда в приложении открывается внешний файл достаточно большого размера, и в этот момент выполняется анимация. Ну так вот, анимация, как и все приложение виснет на этот момент (ну это само собой...) Нужно чтобы анимация так и продолжала работать, без рывков и тормозов, пока в отдельном потоке открывается файл.

.NET 4 (выше нельзя)

студия 2012, если нужно могу скинуть проект...

Comment: Скажите более конкретно, что вам нужно. Существует миллион методов выполнить код в другом потоке.

Comment: Да, также неплохо бы аргументировать, почему именно для WPF, так как сама по себе работа с потоками не зависит от GUI (но при этом от GUI зависит то, как с элементами управления обращаться в потоках)

Comment: Студия используется 2012 или 2010?

Comment: Проект не нужен) Для использования паттерна async/await, про который я упомянул в ответе, с .NET Framework 4.0 существует официальная библиотека - https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async

Answer (score 5):

```
new Thread(() => MyMethod()).Start();
```

Метод в отдельном потоке... В чем проблема-то?

С данными:

```
int i = 0;
new Thread(() => {
    MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
}).Start();
```

Если .Net Framework 4 или выше, то ниже Вам написали пример. Также, что касается примера ниже, читайте про [async/await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx)

Comment: так он не принимает ни каких данных

Answer (score 5):

Для начала, структурируйте вашу программу. Часть, которая занимается представлением (View), должна быть отделена от управляющей части (ViewModel), и от различных движков (Model).

Когда ViewModel решает, что нужно открыть файл, запрос на открытие и разбор содержимого должен уйти в движок разбора файла и построения объектной модели. Модель сама по себе вполне может быть однопоточной, а вот бизнес-логика пусть занимается перебрасыванием информации между потоками.

Итак, на уровне модели ваш код прост и линеен:

```
public Document ReadFromFilename(string filename)
{
    using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
        return ReadFromStream(fs);
}

protected Document ReadFromStream(IStream stream)
{
    ...
```

На уровне VM вам нужно немного больше:

```
public void async OpenDocumentAsync(string filename)
{
    try
    {
        // установить статус ожидания
        this.ReadStatus = ReadStatus.Reading;
        // распарсить документ
        var doc = await DocumentHelper.GetDocumentAsync(filename);
        // создать VM-структуру
        var vmDoc = new VM.Document(doc);
        // установить текущую страницу и создать соответствующие подструктуры
        await vmDoc.SwitchToPageAsync(0);
        // доложить, что всё в порядке
        this.ReadStatus = ReadStatus.Ready;
        // не забыть обновить свойство DataContext'а
        this.Document = vmDoc;
    }
    catch (<что нужно>)
    {
        // доложить, что что-то пошло не так
        this.ReadStatus = ReadStatus.Failed;
    }
}
```

Метод `DocumentHelper.GetDocumentAsync` будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
public Task<Model.Document> GetDocumentAsync(string filename)
{
    var t = new Task(() => model.ReadFromFilename(filename));
    t.Start(taskSchedulers[model]);
    return t;
}
```

Comment: к сожалению мои познания в C# сильно ограничены... поэтому делаю все в одном месте как говориться... о многопоточности задумался только потому что использоваться программа будет на не поворотливом железе. Точнее там HDD забиты так, что читается с них все особо медленно

Comment: Если разделить программу на слои, станет легче. Это супермегагуру могут легко и правильно сделать всё в одной функции, а простым смертным надо разбивать логику на уровни.

Comment: у меня недостаточно для этого знаний, а сроки ограничены... я понимаю что так будет проще и лучше

Comment: Если программирование — ваш рабочий инструмент, вы должны им хорошо владеть. Ну или владеть даром убеждения заказчиков, что «тормозит и крешится — это нормально». Поэтому для следующего проекта я бы посоветовал выучить MVVM.

Answer (score 2):

На выбор:

```
Task.Run(()=> /*code*/);
Task.Factory.StartNew(Method, params);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/181948/winforms-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-gui) я описывал два способа взаимодействия GUI с рабочими потоками.