# Как в приложении wpf отделить основной поток, от потока в котором идут вычисления

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность

Мое приложение добывает запускаемые файлы, все работает, но  вот хочу теперь сделать так, чтобы при открытии формы все расчеты и сбор данные для формы происходил в другом потоке. Пробовал создавать просто потоки отдельные для методов, но invoke в wpf нет, пробовал делать через Task.Factory. тд. Но приложение просто повисает и все. Пробую сейчас диспетчером, но не уверен, что правильно, сам Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke я использую в конструкторе,вот код. Данный код работает все данные собираются проверяются и тд. Вопрос только про поток как организовать.

ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using Test.Model;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace Test.ViewModel
{
    class MainViewModel:DependencyObject
    {
        static ReadyData Rd=new ReadyData();

        private readonly List<Info> Big = Rd.Data();


        public string MyProperty
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(string), typeof(MainViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(""));





        public ICollectionView Items
        {
            get { return (ICollectionView)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
        }


          // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Items.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
           public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(ICollectionView), typeof(MainViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public MainViewModel()
        {

            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                Items = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Big);

            });


        }

    }
}
```

Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace Test.Model
{
    public class ReadyData
    {
      Controller c=new Controller();


        public List<Info> Data()
        {
           List<Info> query = null;
        // Собираю все  результаты  вместе
        string r1 = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; // реестр local mashin
        string r2 = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; //реестр СCurren user


            List<Info> a = c.PrintKeys(r1);
            List<Info> a1 = c.PrintKeys(r2);
            List<Info> aSh = c.PrintTasks();
            List<Info> a3 = c.Startfolder();
            List<Info> result = a.Except(a1).ToList();
            var result1 = aSh.Union(a3);
            List<Info> big = result.Union(result1).ToList();
            // убираю дубликаты записей
              query = big.GroupBy(x => x.Namefile1).Select(y => y.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();

            return query;

        }




}
}
```

View

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Test.ViewModel;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using Test.Model;

namespace Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           DataContext=new MainViewModel();
        }

      // событие откртия окна по клику.

        private void Control_OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            ListView lV = (ListView)sender;

            if (lV.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
             var ggg = (Info)lV.SelectedItem;

             Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("explorer.exe", " /select, " + ggg.Path1));

            }

        }
    }
}
```

xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="916.197" Width="1264.658">
    <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="607" Margin="30,86,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1192" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"  MouseDoubleClick="Control_OnMouseDoubleClick">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>

                        <GridViewColumn Header="Иконка">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding A}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                        <GridViewColumn Header="Имя файла" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Namefile1}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Путь" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path1}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Кпараметры командной строки" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding C1}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Цифровая подпись" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding F1}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Корректность цифровой подписи" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding G1}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Тип запуска" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TipZapuska}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Производитель" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Company}"/>


    </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Window>
```

Comment: Invoke в WPF, кстати, есть. Но вам он не нужен, нужен async/await.

Comment: @VladD мне нужно, чтобы все было организованно в другом потоке, А async/await это же не в чистом виде другой поток или Task

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно выполнить метод в отдельном потоке?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/222414/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight это не дубликат вопроса, я проделывал все, что там написано и знаю как сделать один поток для метода, проблема в том что на уровне VM не получается организовать отдельный поток, и куда смотреть я не знаю, асинкавейт, увы это не отдельный поток . Пробовал использовать Диспетчер, но вроде работает но не в отельном потоке. Буду рад если поможите

Comment: Странно что через `Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> //to do);` не работает. Может попробовать ретернить из метода Task.Run. `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`, `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` или `new Thread()`