# Можно ли использовать интерфейс Icommand совместно с dependency property. в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Возник вопрос на уровне понимания, если у меня есть VIewModel, ее я построил на наследовании класса ViewModel от dependency property. И свойства все работают прекрасно, но вот хочу я сделать команду, которая будет обрабатываться при нажатии кнопки, Вопрос могу ли я на этом же классе VIewModel реализовать интерфейс Icommand, чтобы описать поведение команды. Будет ли это правильно.

Comment: Нет, вы пишите реализацию ICommand (гуглите простейшие реализации RelayCommand/DelegateCommand), а в своей ViewModel вы просто выставляете свойство типа ICommand, которое уже будет отдавать наружу подходящую реализацию (экземпляр DelegateCommand или типа того). Иными словами, VM не является командой сама по себе, но может включать в себя команды (любое количество) и выставлять их в виде свойств, к которым привяжется View.

Comment: @АндрейNOP я так и думал.

Comment: Dependency Property во вьюмодели - это дурная практика, я понимаю, что на русскоязычных ресурсах для начинающих полно подобных примеров, но это в корне неправильно. Эти свойства используются для других задач, например при создании собственных контролов или привязок внутри вьюшки. Во вьюмодели надо использовать `INotifyPropertyChanged` и `ObservableCollection<T>`.

Comment: @Bulson Спасибо за ответ, а поясните подробнее я про дурную практику. У меня возникал вопрос, если я могу сделать то что мне надо исходя из задачи,с помощью DP, тогда чем лучше подход при использовании  INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Логика MVVM подразумевает, что класс VM должен быть полностью независим от View и классов из `System.Windows` и, таким образом, свободно покрываем юнит-тестами. Класс со множеством DP превращается в ад для чтения и редактирования. Для использования DP вам нужно отнаследоваться от `DependencyObject`, что плохо, т.к. такой класс нельзя сделать сериализуемым, в нем переопределены `Equals()` & `GetHashCode()`, к нему можно получить доступ, только из того thread в котором он был создан.

Comment: @Bulson Получается, если мы используем  INotifyPropertyChanged, тогда мы можем свободно пользоваться многопоточностью. А в случае с DP, это невозможно? Или возможно. но это уже будет не MVVM, я вас верно понял? А все таки можно ли увидеть пример использования DP, как показатель того, что он нужен для конструирования контролов.

Comment: VM унаследованная от `DependencyObject` работает строго в thread UI, да вы и сами напоролись на это, судя по вашему вопросу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/874246/222542 , про конструирование контролов тянет на отдельный вопрос, а не на переписку в комментариях.

Comment: @Bulson я как раз и понимаю, тогда у меня действительно стала эта проблема и я не мог понять почему, теперь если мне нужна многопоточность, это только  INotifyPropertyChanged